# Any Mails from Google Compute Engine via sendgrid GMail marks as spam

Tags: gmail, spam, sendgrid, google-compute-engine

I installed on a Google Compute Engine postfix as a MTA.
The Mails are sent via sendgrid.

Now any Mails (tests, errorlogs, cron...) to GMail are marked as Spam.

Sending the same mails from an normal server without sendgrid is no problem.
(I have many root-server and are just trying sendgrid)

Why does google think that every mail from sendgrid is spam?

Comment: Could you post the headers of a message that was marked as spam?

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/115161/fixing-my-mtas-poor-reputation

and Maybe your IP its reported in blacklist.

Try using other reserverved ip address in your instance.

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network

Comment: Thank you. No the IP ist not in a blacklist. And now I tested it with some other server (There I'm sending with sendmail without problems).  It seems that google sets a penality for sending with sendgrid.

Answer (score 0):

For maximum deliverability, SPF and DKIM records need to be setup and properly configured in the DNS records for the domain you want to send mail from. Assuming you signed up for the `[free tier of SendGrid][1]`, available to Google Compute Engine customers:

**SPF**: make sure the string `include:sendgrid.net` is present. The most basic setup would then be `v=spf1 a mx include:sendgrid.net ~all`, if all email for the domain is sent via Sendgrid this is enough. If you have more complex needs, use an SPF builder, such as [Microsoft's](https://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/).

**DKIM**: get it from the Google Apps account manager, under 'Settings for Gmail>Settings for Gmail'

After those two are in the DNS records for the domain in question, use the [Port25 verifier](http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/) to ensure all settings are correct. Of course, if you want to test whether mail from the server is properly setup for deliverability, send them email form the server. Same for email from Outlook, etc.

PS1: *These instructions vary slightly if you are using a [paid version of Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/whitelabel_wizard.html)*

PS2: *All Google Compute Engine IPs are listed in [Spamhaus PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/). Email should not come from these IPs directly (but if you have a specific reason to do so you can contact GCE Support - which is not free - and request that they add a reverse DNS record for you so you can start sending mail from this address directly).*